# Why does RemoteManagementAgent keep starting?

Tags: security, remote-desktop, malware

**Background:** I have witnessed the cursor move on its own on several brief occasions over the past several weeks. I've been reassuring myself that it's just some static discharge going through the trackpad, but I remain suspicious. Today I saw it move a whopping 300 to 400 pixels with my hands nowhere near the trackpad, and that gave me the heebie-jeebies!

Could it be that someone has hacked into my mac and is watching me with a remote desktop app, and is sometimes accidentally bumping their mouse? I installed a lot of software recently so it seems plausible that one of them was malware.

So I looked in activity monitor today and saw these two processes:

- **remotemanagementd**
- **RemoteManagementAgent**

## Strange.

**This is my personal mac** bought as new from Apple and I never installed or enabled any remote desktop/management software, and I do not have screen sharing or remote management enabled in system settings.

So I stopped those two processes and for a while they remained gone. A few hours later, **they're back!** Note: I did not log out or reboot during this time.

**Question(s):** WHAT are those processes and WHY are they restarting themselves?

Furthermore, how can I stop these processes from ever starting, or how can I tell my mac to immediately terminate these processes as soon as they start?

Just kidding guys, mods please delete this pos- HEY, I didn't write that!!!!⌫⌫⌫⌫⌫⌫ STTO⌫O⌫OOAP!!!

Comment: Snort! You might want to Restore macOS, or more drastically, backup your data, then nuke & pave and start afresh. If you have some chops, set up the firewall and/or use LittleSnitch to see if you can detect traffic that shows remote access. Malwarebytes is a good, free malware scanner (no need to purchase the app for a scan & repair) you can use to see if malware is part of the problem.

Comment: See [How do I prevent Remote Access to my Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/437760/85275)

Comment: Hey, thanks. @IconDaemon I already have Little Snitch but it's not showing much activity. Maybe I'm being too paranoid, but given that Little Snitch is probably the most popular network filter on mac, it seems plausible that some malwares would specifically tip toe around it, and maybe that is happening here. I will put restoring macOS on the todo list.

Comment: @Tetsujin Did all of that, except changing my account password & checking iCloud devices. It's very, very, difficult for me to go without wifi for too long, but I will try. But I did change the wifi password and router admin password and disabled bluetooth.

Comment: I would certainly run Malwarebytes. Though it's worth noting that I also have those processes running, even though all Remote Sharing is disabled. So they may be totally harmless and not evidence of intrusion.

Comment: hawk - those were two of the major ones. You can't skip bits because they're inconvenient. Doing half of a set of procedures like this is pointless.