# Command line on IOS IPad Air 4 (I’ve been hacked)

Tags: terminal, command-line, xcode, script, hacking

I have found multiple instances where the only possibility is that I am being remotely hacked through screen mirroring. I believe this for the following reasons:
**Remotely**

1. I have found open tabs/websites I know for a fact I didn’t open. Not even accidentally. They were opened when I was on cellular data and 1,000 miles away.

   a) One of the websites was about how to open the terminal on an IPad.

   b) I have also seen tabs explaining how to use Microsoft shell for adding scripts to IOS.

   c) He was using my Gmail account to send e-mails, which I saw for myself and was home alone.

**Mirroring**

2. I have been on my Mac while he was on it at the same time and watched (and deleted) the different scripts he was adding.

   a) The settings, name, devices doesn’t show a separate device.
   enter code here

**My question is:** How do I go into the terminal,find the script or code that was placed there for the purpose of spying on me and delete it.

**Extra info:** Yes, the person has physical access.Yes this is across all of my Apple devices. Iphone 14, IPad Air 4, MakBook Pro 2017. All on Beta IOS 17, all up to date.

**I have tried the following:**

1. I purchased an additional wi-fi router with service that has a static IP address, which I often call to have changed.
2. Deleted anything and everything Google
3. I have been constantly changing my passwords/passcodes for Apple ID almost weekly, writing them down and putting them in my safe.
4. I have a good VPN that was highly recommended.
5. I am on my 8 out of 10 Apple ID’s from factory resets and not reloading the cloud.

Sorry this is long, but I wanted to get all the info in. This has been going on for the past 3 years.

Comment: This is nearly impossible to analyze without access to the hardware in question. Get in touch with a trustworthy local expert on the matter.

Comment: See this for some clues on Mac - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/437760/how-do-i-prevent-remote-access-to-my-mac for the iPad/Phone, if it's wiped & set up with a new Apple ID, then there is no way to get in, other than knowing your passcode or new iCloud details. There cannot be any software on there from before.

Comment: Just an observation… assuming your device is compromised, it’s not a good idea to restore from a recent backup because you don’t know if that backup is compromised.  Start with  a clean install and see if the problem continues.  If it doesn’t, start syncing your data and manually reinstall your apps one at a time.

Comment: I really appreciate your contribution, but I have mentioned that I have done exactly that on 8 separate occasions. I don’t know if someone could tell me how to get to the command line or terminal on my IPad and/or what  kind of script or coding for to erase.

Comment: You cannot hack around inside an iPhone. There is no command line. There is no simple user access at all. Everything is sandboxed & encrypted. Wiping a phone & setting up with a new Apple ID cannot possibly contain **any** data from a previous incarnation. If someone can get in your phone, they have physical access & know the passcode & Apple ID password.

Comment: When you say "I have found open tabs/websites I know for a fact I didn’t open", which browser are you looking at?