# Hacked on all fronts

Tags: iphone, apple-id

I found this post, and I felt like I had written it. I'm in almost the EXACT SAME situation. I’ve tried everything I know how to do including things I didn’t know how to do that I had to learn how to do! I’ve been through I don’t know how many Apple IDs at this point, I’ve been through 15 laptops, I’ve been through six iPhones. I am completely at my wits end. This person deleted all of my client history for work so I don’t even have a career anymore. I know this is personal, but I can’t figure out who or how… I’m hoping someone can help. Here's the post (which basically describes my situation, almost exactly):

I have found multiple instances where the only possibility is that I am being remotely hacked through screen mirroring. I believe this for the following reasons: Remotely

1. I have found open tabs/websites I know for a fact I didn’t open. Not even accidentally. They were opened when I was on cellular data and 1,000 miles away. a) One of the websites was about how to open the terminal on an IPad. b) I have also seen tabs explaining how to use Microsoft shell for adding scripts to IOS. c) He was using my Gmail account to send e-mails, which I saw for myself and was home alone.
   Mirroring
2. I have been on my Mac while he was on it at the same time and watched (and deleted) the different scripts he was adding. a) The settings, name, devices doesn’t show a separate device. enter code here
   My question is: How do I go into the terminal,find the script or code that was placed there for the purpose of spying on me and delete it.
   Extra info: Yes, the person has physical access.Yes this is across all of my Apple devices. Iphone 14, IPad Air 4, MakBook Pro 2017. All on Beta IOS 17, all up to date.
   I have tried the following:
3. I purchased an additional wi-fi router with service that has a static IP address, which I often call to have changed.
4. Deleted anything and everything Google
5. I have been constantly changing my passwords/passcodes for Apple ID almost weekly, writing them down and putting them in my safe.
6. I have a good VPN that was highly recommended.
7. I am on my 8 out of 10 Apple ID’s from factory resets and not reloading the cloud.
   Sorry this is long, but I wanted to get all the info in. This has been going on for the past 3 years!

So here’s my question… Is it possible that someone could have left some kind of small device with a ridiculous battery life somewhere in my home that I am unaware of that can tap into another device or possibly tap into my network? What are the different possibilities of how something like this could happen? I need ideas for where/how to look so I can get my life back!!

Comment: See [How do I prevent Remote Access to my Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/437760/how-do-i-prevent-remote-access-to-my-mac)